# Can not find file

Tags: scripts

Am new in Ubuntu, I have install kde plasma desktop, and want to install kde base plug in, and I have to run a `configure.sh` script file, and I try to type in:

```
./Home/michael/downloads/document/kdebase/configure.sh
```

it can not find the file but the file is there, How can I run `install.sh` file same place. Can someone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please put here exact error message, that said file not found. Also run this `ls -ahl /Home/michael/downloads/document/kdebase/`, and put here output

Answer (score 0):

First make it executable using `chmod u+x /home/michael/downloads/document/kdebase/configure.sh`

and then execute it using `/home/michael/downloads/document/kdebase/configure.sh`

Answer (score 0):

It seems just a typo error:

`/home` in Ubuntu is `/home` not `/Home`

`Downloads` is with capital D

so I think you must first locate correctly your script.

Anyway the easiest way to do that just open the directory containing the script in GUI using nautilus(file manager) Then just drag and drop the script to the terminal.

To make it executable

```
chmod +x /The-dragged-path
```

Then run it:

```
./The-dragged-path
```

You may need be sudo

```
sudo ./The-dragged-path
```